# Returning false from custom events produces error in new jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am getting the error **"e.preventDefault is not a function"** in new jquery versions whenever returning false from a custom event handler.

Example : 
        My Dialog Widget created in Jquery has "beforeopen" custom event. A user can prevent the opening of dialog by returning false from the event handler.

```
* Binding the custom event *
$("dialogElement").on("beforeopen",function(){
      return false;
});

* Triggering *

 var returnValue = $("dialogElement").trigger($.Event("beforeopen"));
 if(returnValue){

    ... open the dialog ....

 }
```

This works for me before. But new jquery versions(2.2.4 onwards) produces the mentioned error. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return false; also prevents progressing of other javascript functions. Because of absent of a specific event, command cant understand the event needs to be stopped. Maybe being more specific by using the code below could help you;

```
$("dialogElement").on("beforeopen",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```